# How to get the process id of different tabs in browsers - python

Tags: python-3.x, winapi, process

I want to get the process id of the currently active tab in browsers. I know all browsers doesn't create a different process for each tab but chrome and edge do so. Just like in browser task manager we can see different PID of each tab.

Below code can give me the title of tabs in browser. But it gives a common handle and common id to all tabs which I think is the id of the main browser. If two tabs have same title how will I differentiate between them?
PS - Any unique id assigned to each tab can be helpful like process-id, session-id or anything else.

```
time.sleep(3)
i = 0
while i < 1:
    hwnd = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
    pid = win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd)
    title = win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd)
    print(" handle : {} title: {}".format(hwnd,title))
    processinfo([pid[-1]])
    pr = psutil.Process(pid[-1])
    children = pr.children()
    for child in children:
        print("Child id: {} name : {} exe: {}".format(child.pid,child.name,child.exe()))
    i = i + 1
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: why you decide that exist 1 to 1 mapping between tab and process ?

Comment: @RbMm You can see that in the Browser's task manager (in chrome press SHIFT+ESC).

Comment: this is very specific for concrete application and not related to generic winapi. if concrete application export some "interface" which allow get this info - you can use it. and solutions will be different for every browser

Comment: So you are saying that it is up to the browser to assign process id to tabs but the system do have the info about this process id. I can see all the different process corresponding to chrome in my windows task manager too just like in browser's task manager.

Comment: no, system have no any info about this. how i and say this is specific for concrete application.

Comment: Press SHIFT+ESC in chrome to see the process ID seems to be consistent with the PID obtained in your code, I do not know what process ID you still need?